# Extjs 4.0 : how to copy a cell content in gird, I' m using Extjs 4.0

Tags: grid, copy, extjs4, cell

I need to select and copy the grid cell content. How to implement this?
I'm new to Extjs , and I am using Extjs 4.0. 
Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile there is a built-in solution: add [`enableTextSelection: true`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-cfg-enableTextSelection)

```
viewConfig: {
    enableTextSelection : true
}
```

This will allow the selection

Answer (score -2):

Currently there is no way, read [this entry in Sencha Forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?135494-Make-grid-unselectability-a-boolean-attribute)

Comment: If there is no straight solutions,then how to fix this by editing the css file?Expecting for your answer,thanks!